# Facebook: How to update the status from the page profile?

Tags: php, facebook, api, parsing

I have a problem with cross-posting to Facebook. I can post some info to my personal wall (used parsing or Facebook API), but I need to post to the page of a group (ex: facebook.com/pages/$Pagename/$PageId ). (I am manager on this group and can post manually, but need the same functionality automatically from my site.)

And I have errors each time I try to do the posting automatically to my own group:(

1) When I use parsing I get message 'The post could not be shared.'
(from m.facebook.com/sharer.php?error=1&_rdr )

2) When I use parsing and send post-data through m.facebook.com/a/home.php?refid=$NumberID 
I can post the message from the group page. But if the message contains a link, it is posted on behalf of my profile, but I want to make a post from the group page with link on my site.

3) When I make posting through Facebook API -- I get the error (#200) - "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

I make server authentication. And I want make this without permissions query of the current user (therefore tried parsing).

again:
I can update own(!) status through this three methods (with link too). I need update profile of my page (message with link).
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by “parsing”?

Comment: What permissions are you granting to the app you're using to make the posts in case 3? are you missing the `publish_stream` permission?

Comment: Case 1and 2:
I mean DOM-parser and use PHP cURL to grab HTML from Facebook

Comment: Thanks, Igy.
I have in case 3 `publish_stream` permission (and `manage_pages` too is needed).

But when message has link on my site, it is posted behalf my profile.
When message has no link on site, it is ok. (Posted behalf my page profile)